# Knockout subscribe is evaluating unexpectedly

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-subscribe

I need a timestamp for when a value is updated. For reasons I won't go into here, the `value` is a writable computed that points to a `valueInstance` observable, so they basically show the same data.

If I subscribe to the observable it works as expected, only fires when the observable changes. If I subscribe to the computed it fires immediately causing a false timestamp, even though the observable is still undefined. What's up with this?

http://jsfiddle.net/bNXhm/

**Update:** looks like this only happens when the computed has `deferEvaluation: true`

http://jsfiddle.net/bNXhm/1/

```
function VM(){
    var self = this;

    self.valueInstance = ko.observable();
    self.value = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.valueInstance();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            self.valueInstance(value);
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    });

    self.timeStamp1 = ko.observable();
    self.value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        self.timeStamp1(new Date());
    });

    self.timeStamp2 = ko.observable();
    self.valueInstance.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        self.timeStamp2(new Date());
    }); }
```

Comment: What is your question ? I don't see any unexpected behavior.

Comment: `value.subscribe` is firing on the initial load even though `value` has not changed. subscribe should only fire when the value changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an observable it will be evaluated unless you set deferEvaluation to true.
When an observable (or computed) is evaluated it always notify them subscribers. There no  comparison with the previous value at this point (in order to notify only if the value changes).

The "useless notification check" is made in the setter of the observable.

So in your code, when you use deferEvaluation at false, the read function is immediately evaluated and the subscribers will are notifed. But there is no subscribers at this time. That's why the timespan is not set.

And when you use deferEvaluation : true, the evaluation process is delay in the applyBindings function. At this time you already subscribed and that's why the timespan will is set.

To solve your problem, I would create a variable to store when you should start to logged changes.

```
function VM(){

    var self = this;
    self.logged  = false;


    self.valueInstance = ko.observable();
    self.value = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self.valueInstance();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            self.valueInstance(value);
        },
        deferEvaluation: true
    });

    self.timeStamp1 = ko.observable();
    self.value.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if(self.logged)
            self.timeStamp1(new Date());
    });

    self.timeStamp2 = ko.observable();
    self.valueInstance.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        if(self.logged)
             self.timeStamp2(new Date());
    });
}
var vm  = new VM();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.logged = true;
```

I hope it helps

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bNXhm/2/)

Answer (score 1):

When you `deferEvalaution` the computed is not evaluated until someone requests its value.  This happens when it is bound.  When it is evaluated, it notifies any subscribers. This would explain why your subscription is hit.